# Pandas replace part of string with values from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I would like to replace the words in my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Text": ["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]})
```

which match the keys in the following dictionary

```
dic = {"quick brown fox": "fox",
       "lazy dog": "dog}
```

with their values.

The expected outcome is

```
    Text
0   The fox jumps over the dog
```

I tried the following code but there is no change to my df.

```
df["Text"] = df["Text"].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([dic.get(i, i) for x in x.split()]))
```

I would like to know if there is any way to do this? I have a dataframe with around 15k rows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `.replace` with `regex=True`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {"quick brown fox": "fox", "lazy dog": "dog", "u": "you"}
#Update as per comment
dic = {r"\b{}\b".format(k): v for k, v in dic.items()}

df = pd.DataFrame({"Text": ["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]})
df["Text"] = df["Text"].replace(dic, regex=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                         Text
0  The fox jumps over the dog
```

Comment: As my dictionary is used to replace contraction and acronyms, it is quite comprehensive. I have a key value pair which is `{"u": "you"}`. This causes the output to change to `"The fox jyoumps over the dog"`. Do you know of any way to get around this?

Comment: @Amas use `dic = {r"\b{}\b".format(k): v for k, v in dic.items()}`. Updated snippet

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `for` loop with [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
for pat, repl in dic.items():
    df.Text = df.Text.str.replace(pat, repl)
```

[out]

```
                         Text
0  The fox jumps over the dog
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `replace` method of the `str` accessor along with a regex generated from the keys of `dic`:

```
df['Text'].str.replace('|'.join(dic), lambda string: dic[string.group()])
```

Output:

```
0    The fox jumps over the dog
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Finally, some working solution!